# Unable to locally debug because sql connection string is being ignored

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, sql-server-2008, windows-server-2008, windows-8, visual-studio-2012

I'm currently attempting to debug a solution that I've picked up as a side project but I'm not having much luck. The solution depends on data (user IDs, page content, etc) stored on an MSSQL server on my local network, but when I execute the solution in VS2012 debug mode the connection fails. The error I'm getting says that the connection failed, and that the user was rejected.

When I log into the SQL server and check the event logs I can see where the login ID was rejected, but it was rejected because it wasn't the login ID that I specified in the connection string. It seems to be trying to use my windows authentication instead (which in windows 8 is a live ID) which won't work because my windows ID doesn't (and shouldn't) have access to the server.

Some basic connection string info (all data changed to protect the innocent... aka my poor server)

```
Data Source=myServer; Initial Catalog=myDB; User ID=myUsername; Password=myPassword; Integrated Security=false;
```

Has anyone run into this issue?

Comment: are they using EF of L2S? if so, the connection may be nested in the properties of the designer...

Comment: I've had something similar occur because I had the connection string misnamed and the code (machine generated) included a default value...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do a search in the *entire solution* for `myServer`. This should shed light on the issue, given the connection string is defined somewhere else and it connects to the same server.

Comment: I'll look into it tonight when I get home and let you know. At the moment I can say that 'it works in production' but then again it could be doing the same thing in prod (though I don't believe it is).

Comment: I'm an idiot, the issue was a combination of this and the TCP/IP setting in SQL configuration management for 2008 being set to 'off' by default (in spite of me specifying during install that the server must accept external requests).